# How to add context (not on the page) for screen readers?

Tags: accessibility, usability, screen-readers

For good accessibility, should the text for screen readers be the same text as the web page?

Issue I am pondering: Context may be different for someone who cannot see the item "in context" visually.

For example:

My page has a table with a header row with text "Total : 200"
200 being the number of rows.

I can add `aria-label` for 'Number of orders is 200' for the screen reader on the actual 200 (it's within a span) so that the screen reader doesn't just say "200".

My question is should the aria label be something more descriptive like 'Total number of records is 200' given the lack of context for the visually impaired user.  Or is it OK because they will have their own context from knowing how and why they navigated there, assuming a fairly simple page such as my example where essentially the page is a table of records.

Comment: It's difficult to give a good answer to your specific example without seeing a portion of your code. I'm curious as to why you're putting the total number of rows in a table heading row. This seems wrong. I'm also not sure that `aria-label` is the right choice here. If this is a static table, then the screen reader will announce the number of rows and columns. However, if this is a searchable/sortable dynamic table, then there are other techniques that may serve you better. If you can provide more details and possibly an example, that would be helpful.

Comment: It's beneficial to everybody, not just blind or VI, if you write "200 records" or "There are 200 records" visible for everyone. When doing accessibility, it's generally better to minimize specialties and use them only where they are really needed / useful. And +1, the number of records should probably not be in a table header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [caption](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption) to describe the `table` and then there'll be context.

If adding `caption` adds redundancy of context, like there are already headings to know the context, you may use `sr-only` CSS class to hide it from the UI but keep it for the screen readers. The below snippet is from the Bootstrap CSS.

```
// Only display content to screen readers
// See: http://a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-hide-content/
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  border: 0;
}
```

Avoid `aria` attributes if HTML semantic tags serve the purpose.